# Create git diff between two directories and apply patch to directory

Tags: git, diff, patch

My goal is to create a diff between two folders so that file changes can be applied easily.

My current command:

```
git diff --no-index --binary 20140902/ 20141227/ > 01.diff
```

The diffs of each file look like this:

```
diff --git a/20140902/Documents/sheet.xlsx b/20141227/Documents/sheet.xlsx
index 3d0d2c8acd53eb068ac5d390048e7f624dd012b9..fe5a87dd3b99874746e137d752fa6b151544c0ca 100644
GIT binary patch
delta 11480
...
```

How can I apply this diff to a folder `current` which has the same contents as `20140902` (or if necessary, to a folder named `20140902`)?

When I try

```
cd current/
git apply ../01.diff
```

I get

```
error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 3)
```

where line 3 is line "GIT binary patch". Maybe the lines in diff file should look like

```
diff --git a/Documents/sheet.xlsx b/Documents/sheet.xlsx
```

?

Comment: Do the folders contain binary files? You could probably omit the `--binary` flag if they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: try `git apply -p2 ...`.

#### Description

The *right* setup is not completely clear to me from your posting, so I will show my setup:

```
$ mkdir tpatch
$ cd tpatch
$ mkdir -p 20140902/Documents 20141227/Documents
$ printf 'binary\0stuff' > 20140902/Documents/foo
$ printf 'different\0binary' > 20141227/Documents/foo
$ git diff --no-index --binary 20140902/ 20141227/ > 01.diff
```

(The resulting patch is indeed a `GIT binary patch` thanks to the NULs in the `printf` output above, though mine has two `literal`s instead of a `delta`.)

Next, I created a repository in the directory `current`.  If your repository is at a different level, you might need a different `-p` value:

```
$ mkdir current; cd current; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .../tmp/tpatch/current/.git/
$ cp -r ../20140902/Documents .
$ ls
Documents
$ git add . && git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) ee60bbe] initial
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Documents/foo
```

Note that at this point I get the same error with a plain `git apply`, becuase stripping `a/` from the diff leaves Git with `20140902/Documents/foo`, not `Documents/foo`:

```
$ git apply ../01.diff 
error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 3)
```

However, by using `-p2`, we tell Git to remove *two* components (`a/20140902/`) from the path, after which the file name `Documents/foo` matches the one in the repository and work-tree:

```
$ git apply -p2 ../01.diff
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Documents/foo

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If you have a more complex situation, you might need to use the `--src-prefix` and/or `--dst-prefix` options in the `git diff` command in the first place, but probably just `-p2` will do the trick.

Comment: using --no-prefix for git diff makes git apply, which defaults to -p1, mostly work. But I have issues with renaming files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858586/does-git-apply-p-leading-slash-removal-not-work-for-renames