# Does git apply -p (leading slash removal) not work for renames?

Tags: git, diff, patch

Here is a simple diff file from  `git diff --no-index --no-prefix dir1 dir2 > dir.diff`:

```
diff --git dir1/file1.txt dir2/file1.txt
index 45b983b..ce01362 100644
--- dir1/file1.txt
+++ dir2/file1.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hi
+hello
diff --git dir1/file2.txt dir2/file2_rename.txt
similarity index 100%
rename from dir1/file2.txt
rename to dir2/file2_rename.txt
diff --git dir1/file3.txt dir1/file3.txt
deleted file mode 100644
index b1a17ba..0000000
--- dir1/file3.txt
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-zzz
diff --git dir2/file4.txt dir2/file4.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f761ec1
--- /dev/null
+++ dir2/file4.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+bbb
```

As you can see, file1.txt is modified, file2.txt is renamed, file3.txt is deleted, and file4.txt is added.

Now when I try to apply the patch:

```
cp -r dir1 dir_work
cd dir_work
git apply -v ../dir.diff
```

I get the following verbose output, indicating the patch failed on file2 rename: (patch works perfectly without file2)

```
Checking patch file1.txt...
Checking patch dir1/file2.txt => dir2/file2_rename.txt...
error: dir1/file2.txt: No such file or directory
Checking patch file3.txt...
Checking patch file4.txt...
```

So for file1, file3, file4, the leading directories (`dir1/...` and `dir2/...`) were stripped (`-p1` is `git apply` default), but not for the rename? How can I strip the leading directory for file2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the code that detects the file rename, and the old and new names, uses the two lines:

> ```
> rename from dir1/file2.txt
> rename to dir2/file2_rename.txt
> ```

which as you can see include the `dir1/` and `dir2/` parts, but not an `a/` nor `b/` part.  This would still be true even if you hadn't used `--no-prefix` in the `git diff` command.

In the end, `git apply`'s `-p1` option, which would normally strip just `a/` and `b/`, is now stripping `dir1/` and `dir2/` from the *other* diff lines, but does not do anything with these two lines.  Internally, `git apply` strips one fewer prefixes than `git apply` does in general:

```
static int gitdiff_renamesrc(struct gitdiff_data *state,
                             const char *line,
                             struct patch *patch)
{
        patch->is_rename = 1;
        free(patch->old_name);
        patch->old_name = find_name(state->root, line, NULL,
             state->p_value ? state->p_value - 1 : 0, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

Using `git diff` *without* `--no-prefix` and `git apply -p2`, Git will thus strip *one* component from these two names.  So it may help to use `-p2` on the `apply` step, instead of `--no-prefix` on the `git diff` command.

Comment: The fact that rename line does not have prefixes and so the code strips one fewer prefix is surprising to me. Given that, the `-p2` solution works as expected.